# return 1. Как с этим работать?

Tags: c++, строки, visual-c++

На CodeWars есть задачка перевернуть строку. Прогнал через for с конца. Но не засчитывается. Пишет "no suitable constructor exists return 1".

```
std::string reverseString(std::string str)
{
    /*std::string revString = str;
    int b = 0;
    for (std::size_t a = str.size() - 1; a <= 0; a--) {
        revString[b] = str[a];
        b++;
    }
    std::cout << revString << std::endl; - мой код*/
    return 1;
}
```

Complete the solution so that it reverses the string passed into it.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std ; 

string reverseString (string str )
{
  /* your code here */
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: std::string должна возвращать функция, вы возвращаете int

Comment: выводить `revString ` не на экран надо, а вернуть через `return revString`

Comment: Уважаемый участник сайта , следовало бы изучить как задвать вопросы [Как правильно задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Главный вопрос у вас про return 1 , а внутри уже спрашиваете другое.

Comment: Вы знаете как работают функции? Может стоит сначала подучить азы программирования, а потом решать подобные задачи? У функции тип возвращаемого значение – `std::string`, а Вы возвращаете 1. Плюс зачем-то печатаете неизвестно куда строку-результат.

Comment: И вообще, у Вас вся функция по сути закомменчена, так и отправляли на проверку?

Comment: @V-Mor Ну нет, конечно. Это лишь выделить написанное мной от заданных условностей.

Comment: @V-Mor Я бы с удовольствием не возвращал 1, но в условиях задачи это необходимо.

Comment: @БилолбекАтабеков Ну потому что в условиях задачи требуется именно через return 1. Я показал как я изначально попытался, а спрашиваю как можно с return 1.

Comment: Условие задачи в студию. Не может быть чтобы при возвращаемом значении типа `std::string` просили вернуть 1. Возможно, Вы что-то не так поняли.

Comment: @SKIP Это из-за условия задачи. Я бы и сам вернул бы string, но там надо именно через 1.

Comment: @V-Mor 
std::string reverseString(std::string str)
{
 ваш код//
 return 1;
}

Comment: Добавьте полностью всю задачу с условием, а главное с требованиями ко вводу и выводу значений, в попрос.

Comment: @V-Mor Добавил. Насколько я понял, всё за пределами должно скобок должно быть неизменно.

Comment: Жиза косит наши ряды, СПАСАЙТЕСЬ!!!

1) если функция объявлена, как возвращающая `string`, почему возвращаем  целое? 2) Карл, где функция `main`?

Comment: Функция main в другой единице трансляции)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы решил вашу задачу так:

```
// Complete the solution so that it reverses the string passed into it.

#include <string>
using namespace std ;

string reverseString (string str )
{
  /* your code here */
  return string(str.rbegin(), str.rend());} int foo() {

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: А как можно сделать подобное в функции и exit code через 1?

Comment: Почитал комментарии и добавил решение задачи))

Comment: Благодарю! Теперь осталось самому понять как это работает!)

Comment: Я просто объявил новую функцию foo, которая и возвращает эту злосчастную единицу

Comment: Да блин, зачем он тогда вообще нужна? Хах.

Answer (score 1):

Вот рабочий код для того, чтобы перевернуть текст с готовй функцией *reverse* с библиотеки *algorithm*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   string str = "test string";
   
   reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
   
   cout << str << std::endl;
 
   return 0;
}
```

Вот циклический вывод реверсивно

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string arr;
    getline(cin, arr);
    for(int x=arr.size()-1; x>=0; x--){
        cout << arr[x];
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

А в целом про return:
return это команда закончить текущую функцию (и вернуть значение вызыающей функции)

```
return 0
```

если это return в main() то программа закнчивается.
А если указать `return 1`

> Implementation defined.

Обычно работает так же как и EXIT_FAILURE.

Comment: А как можно то же самое с return 1 провернуть?

Comment: У вас точно просят с return 1? и он должен быть в main ?

Comment: Нет, должен быть в функции. И да, return 1 насколько я понял. Обновил вопрос, там показана изначальная задача.